# RShiny: RandomForest Variable lengths differ, only when reactive

Tags: r, shiny, regression, random-forest

I am very new at using R shiny. I am trying to create an app that helps to create a RandomForest model on a predetermined dataset.

I have gotten stuck at the point of the model, however. The plan is to have the model be created based on a checkbox and radio button on the UI side. However, the model only works when these elements are not reactive.
So
        `rfmodel <- randomForest(ADJOE ~ TOR, data=df_train, mtry=5)`  works fine.
But  `rfmodel <- randomForest(input$outcome ~ TOR, data=df_train, mtry=5)` does not.
the error is: variable lengths differ (found for 'TOR').

The input$outcome should be exactly the same as ADJOE. As a test I have also used the input$outcome variable to subset the train_data I am also using to generate the model, using the following code

`names <- colnames(df_valid)`
`testsubset <- names[names %in% input$outcome]`
`df_train <- df_train[testsubset]`
which works fine.

I simply do not know how input$outcome can be different from ADJOE in this case.

My code for getting the outcomevariable is:

`radioButtons("outcome", "Outcome Variable",`

`choices = c("ADJOE", "ADJDE", "EFG_O", "EFG_D", "TOR", "TORD", "FTR", "FTRD", "X2P_O", "X2P_D", "X3P_O", "X3P_D"),`
`selected = "ADJOE"),`

and my code for creating the model is:
`rfmodel <- randomForest(input$outcome ~ TOR, data=df_train, mtry=5)`

using a trimmed down version of the college basketball dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/andrewsundberg/college-basketball-dataset

which was trimmed down using
`df <- csv[,c(5,6, 8:11, 14:19)]`

I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reformulate`.

```
rfmodel <- randomForest(reformulate('TOR', input$outcome), data=df_train, mtry=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste`

```
rfmodel <- randomForest(as.formula(paste0(input$outcome, " ~ TOR")),
        data = df_train, mtry = 5)
```